# How to send user information obtained from iPhone app to Website (Joomla)?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, joomla

In my iphone app, I want the user to enter his email address.  I need to send this email address to my website which uses Joomla.

What should be done on iphone side as well as Website(Joomla) side for this?

Please Help and Suggest.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a web service in joomla. and then when users enter their email address, you call this service in iphone app. quite typical way server-mobile communication

Comment: Hi Thanks for your input. Can you explain on which kind of webservice is to be implemented in Joomla. can u please give some good articles or tutorials to which we can refer?How to call this webservice from iphone i.e. in Objective-C?

Comment: In Joomla side, you can implement whatever kind of webservice that you like, but personal experience tell me using REST web service is better. take a look on that might help http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=304&t=501897 and the objective C is easier, just like the following comment:

Comment: NSString *output= [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:YOURURLHERE] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    
NSDictionary *theObject=[output JSONValue];

Answer (score 0):

You can use BlueFrameForms for Joomla which allows you to pass parameters to custom forms.